# "Mechanism design" vs "Implementation theory"

Tags: definition, mechanism-design

The terms [mechanism design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanism_design) and [implementation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implementation_theory) seem to me closely related: in both fields, we are given some objective function, and we want to "implement" it, that is, construct a "mechanism" that optimizes the objective function. Are these really two equivalent terms? If not, what is the difference?